# Point Root domain to Heroku with static IP

Tags: heroku, dns, appdomain

Help! I have an app on **Heroku** and free **QuotaGuard** plugin, which gave me two static IP addresses: "**Your Static IPs are** 54.72.12.1 & 54.72.77.249". Also, I have a domain name ***learn-reactjs.ru***. In my DNS-master I pointed records:

- www CNAME www.learn-reactjs.ru.herokudns.com.
- @ A 54.72.12.1
- @ A 54.72.77.249

But if I go to ***learn-reactjs.ru*** I will get a Heroku error "How did you end up here?". At the same time, I can go to ***www.learn-reactjs.ru*** without any problems.

How can I point root domain correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. I refused static IPs and started using CloudFlare. I set their name servers in my domain provider and my site started working well! After this, I attached SSL certificate which I get in CloudFlare. With the help of CloudFlare, everything turned out to be very simple!